# Modern equivalent of saja

Tags: одним-словом

I saw a reference to an old Russian measurement called Saja, if that is the correct pronunciation. What is the modern day equivalent of that?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you are asking about **сажень**:

> 1 сажень = 7 English feet = 84 inches = 2,1336 meters

It is not used since 1924 when metric system became mandatory.

Currently it is mentioned in proverbs and other sayings only, like "Косая сажень в плечах", etc. (Technically "косая сажень" is bigger measure than "сажень").

Good article is on [Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a picture of what [сажень](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWtuZ.jpg) is.[image]